# Azure Table Query Pricing

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I emitted a query against a azure table. That query returned 300 rows (no continuation token). Reading those results counts as 1 "get" transaction or 300? What if there were continuation tokens involved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each query is one transaction even if it doesn't return any data or returns just continuation token (but no entities) or returns entities with or without any continuation token.

Comment: its not that i dont trust you, but can you provide some documentation maybe?

Comment: :) you may find this blog post useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx

Comment: Trust in Gaurav you must have - Yoda  ;-)